# How to run a job in Spring Boot between 9:30 am to 4:00 pm every 5 mins?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Currently I have the following 2 cron expressions configured in the application but the job runs past 4:00 pm.

As show in the application logs below I see logger statements even after 4:00 pm. Not sure why.

**application.properties**

```
#Starts at 9:30 AM and ends at 10:00 AM. Runs every 5 mins
job.cron1=0 30-55/5 9 * * MON-FRI
#Starts at 10:00 AM and ends at 4:00 PM. Runs every 5 mins
job.cron2=0 */5 10-16 * * MON-FRI
```

**PurgeData.java**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron1}")
public void purgeDBData1() {
    log.info("Purging DB data every 5 mins between 9:30 am - 10:00 am...");
}


@Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron2}")
public void purgeDBData2() {
    log.info("Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...");
}
```

**Application Logs:**

```
2021-03-02 16:05:20,801 INFO job.PurgeDataJob [scheduling-1] Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...
2021-03-02 16:10:20,801 INFO job.PurgeDataJob [scheduling-1] Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...
...
....
.....
2021-03-02 16:45:20,801 INFO job.PurgeDataJob [scheduling-1] Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...
2021-03-02 16:50:20,801 INFO job.PurgeDataJob [scheduling-1] Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...
2021-03-02 16:55:20,801 INFO job.PurgeDataJob [scheduling-1] Purging DB data every 5 mins between 10:00 am - 4:00 pm...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two crons to handle a start at the half-past nine. The common part is each 5 seconds from Monday to Friday. Remember the latter values are inclusive, so the range must be to `15`, which is `3pm`.

The hour and minute span differs:

- `0 30/5 9 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *` - where `30/5 9` means every 5 minutes starting at 9:30am only for the 9th hour (so up to 10am, exclusive).
- `0 0/5 10-15 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *` - where `0/5 10-15` means every 5 mintes starting at 10am up to 4pm (exclusive)

You will need to use [`@Schedules`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Schedules.html) to define nested `@Scheduled` annotations.

```
@Schedules ({
    @Schedule(cron = "${job.cron1a}"),       // a cron with 9:30am to 9:59am
    @Schedule(cron = "${job.cron1b}")        // a cron with 10am to 16pm
})
public void purgeDBData1() {
    log.info("Purging DB data every 5 mins between 9:30 am - 10:00 am...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. A qq: Wanted it for every 5 mins  and not 5 seconds. I believe the expressions are going to change, correct ?

Comment: Right, I have fixed the cron and its description.

Comment: One more question: What does the ? represent and doesn't the length of spring cron expression be 6. I see 7 here.

Comment: The cron length (fields count) is not fixed and it can contain *at most* 7 fields. I recommend you reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron and then do some experiments here: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html.

Comment: Thanks, will certainly take a look to understand more about this.

Answer (score 2):

You should configure it as following

```
job.cron2=0 */5 10-15 * * MON-FRI
```